# Where is the asari widow's journal?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I talked to an Asari widow in the Citadel and she (it?) says she wants a message from her fallen bondmate. I'm willing to help the gal out, but I need to know where to look for the thing.

**Where is the message the asari widow is seeking?**

Comment: Is it the one in the shop? Or the one standing by herself staring out into the Presidium?

Comment: @Tristan I believe the one in the shop links to the mission entitled *Krogan Dying Message*.

Comment: @DMA57361 Ah, you are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the Kallini: Ardat-Yakshi Monastery mission, a cutscene will play upon examination of the corpse wherein you discover that there is a bomb in the Great Hall of the monastery. You will find yourself facing into an open doorway.

Go on to the next room and bypass the door. There is nothing of interest in this room except for the door, but once you pass into the next corridor there is a PDA beside another corpse on the right hand side. Pick it up to gain 20 experience and the mission Citadel: Asari Widow. In this room you will also meet Samara, if she's alive.

[image]

View the walk through [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?src_vid=v3KhFOZ23fY&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_522992&v=U7XxInw8Ydc#t=36).

Answer (score 4):

You'll run into her during the Ardat-Yakshi Monastery quest. Once you land in the Monstary, you'll slide down the elevator shaft, jump a gap into the room.

Once you enter the room and move  to the next 2 rooms into the next corridor there is a PDA beside another corpse on the righthand side. Pick it up to listen to the journal.

Once you head back to Citadel, you can deliver this journal to the bondmate, Weshra, found at Presidium commons.